# Windows 8 DirectX SwapChainBackgroundPanel Questions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, directx

I come from two distinct backgrounds: I have much experience with WPF/XAML/C# app development and equal experience with C++/DirectX development. I hear about the ability to use DirectX and XAML together and I get all excited, but now I have hit this wall.

I'm trying to use the SwapChainBackgroundPanel in a WPF application. But I'm trying to use C# as the underlying language. I keep running into issues where, regardless of the type of C# project I create (PCL, WPF, Windows Store) none of these types are defined [namely I've been looking for SwapChainBackgroundPanel and some other DX stuff like the device and etc.)

So my question is: how does this work in C#? I've seen the simple shooter example from the MSDN done in C++ and it makes sense; I get it. But I feel like I'm missing one of those "gotcha's" when trying to do it in C#.

Any advice, or maybe a link to an example, or at best a little tutorial on setting up a C#/XAML/DX app would be amazing. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SwapChainBackgroundPanel available to a WPF app (that is in PresentationCore).  The closest you are going to get is the [D3DImage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx), but it's not exactly the same.  [See this discussion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/15/combining-xaml-and-directx.aspx).

I don't think you can fully utilize the DirectX capabilities of a Windows 8 Store app (SwapChainBackgroundPanel) from C#.  You're going to have to do your DirectX work in C++ as in the example you described.  You can certainly combine the three (Xaml, C#, C++) as in [this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SurfaceImageSource-58f7e4d5), but I don't think a 100% C# app is possible.

Comment: Thanks! I was sort of drawing that conclusion but wanted to ask. Upvote for saving me hours of inane research.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is wrong. It is possible to fully utilize C# throught a wrapper.
I did this myself with SharpDx which is actually one of the microsoft recommendations to use DirectX in C#.

As for the choice of XAML Library, Universal Windows App 10 or Windows Store App 8 is the way to go. Use a SwapChainPanel instead of SwapChainBackgroundPanel.

Comment: WPF is possible but it'll be complicated and not recomended.

Comment: what answer?  looks like this should be a comment on some other answer.  if you don't have enough rep to comment, then you'll need to [ask] to get some first.